# My proof of the Euler's Criterion using subgroups of $U(P)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, quadratic-residues

Euler's Criterion claims that $A^{\frac{(P-1)}{2}} \equiv_P \Bigl(\frac{A}{P}\Bigr)$ for prime $P$. My proof will use the fact that QRs forms a subgroup under modular multiplicative group $U(P)$. Then we will be able to utilize the Lagrange's theorem because we know the order of this subgroup.

$$Q = \lbrace x: x \equiv y^2 \space \text{for} \space x, y \in U(P) \rbrace$$

1. Since $1$ is a QR for any $P$, identity will always be in this particular set.
2. Our set is closed under modular multiplication since multiplication of QRs will always be a QR.
3. Our set is closed under inverses as it can be easily shown:

$$x \in Q$$
$$x \equiv y^2$$

Then since multiplication of $x$ with it's inverse is congruent to $1$ (a QR),

$$y^2x^{-1} \equiv 1$$

the multiplication of $x^{-1}$ with a QR is congruent to a QR. This is only possible if $x^{-1} \in Q$. Hence our set is closed under inverses.

$Q$, fulfills all the conditions to be a subgroup of $U(P)$. Hence it is. Since any element in a group to the order of the group is equal to the identity by Lagrange's theorem, same holds true here.

We know that cardinality of $Q$ is $\frac{P-1}{2}$. Hence for $\forall A \in Q$,

$$A^{\frac{P-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \equiv \Bigl(\frac{A}{P}\Bigr).$$

Other part of the proof is trivial. It depends on the field property stating that square root of the identity is either $-1$ or $+1$. And also the fact that a $n$th degree equation have $n$ solutions.

What do you think of my proof. Is it correct?

Comment: Why not show/use that $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}^\times$ is cyclic generated by $g$ so $A = g^m$ and it is a square iff $m$ is even iff $p-1$ divides $m (p-1)/2$ iff $A^{(p-1)/2}=g^{m (p-1)/2}= 1$, otherwise $m$ is odd and $A^m=g^{m (p-1)/2}=g^{(p-1)/2}= -1$

Comment: Yeah, i know. I am just trying to find alternative proof so i can ensure i understand the subject to it's core